# Proper use of Bootstrap 3 Tooltip on a PHP based system

Tags: php, jquery, silverstripe, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have been trying to get this tooltip code to initialize on a page and I cannot get the jQuery to connect properly.

We have PHP running on Ubuntu and we are using Silverstripe. I cannot get the following script to work, no matter where or what file I add it to. I have even tried calling it in from a separate file and it also did not initialize.

How would I add this code to a PHP or SS file? (Silverstripe CMS file)

```
$(function () {

 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

})  

<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default help-tool\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"Below you will find state-by-state breakdowns in Federal, State, and where available Local categories. 
            Explore the data by clicking the map or by clicking the magnifying lens in the table view.\"><i class=\"fa fa-info-circle fa-fw\"></i></button>
```

Comment: You sure you add it after the jquery, and bootstrap javascript ?

Comment: Do you have the propper `data` elements on the items you need to have a tool-tip? ie `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"`

Comment: The data portions should be good to go, trying to figure out a way to get this to fire. I have bootstrap.min.js > jquery.js > then the call for the tooltip gets called in on a separate silverstripe PHP page.

Comment: If your order of inclusion is `bootstrap > jquery`, it won't work.

Comment: Nevermind, It is as follows:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Then, the call for the tooltip is called from a separate file that loads a part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two causes that come to mind here. First, it's possible that the $ is getting interpreted by SS's template parser as a variable expression. I would expect you would be getting an error if that is the case. Second, as Sumit Kukreja indicated it's likely that jQuery and Bootstrap are being injected at the bottom of your template and this code is getting executed before those are loaded.

**Option 1**: To verify if this is happening you could add the following code to Page_Controller::init() or mysite/_config.php:

```
Requirements::set_write_js_to_body(false);
```

Which will cause all required javascript to be added in the `<head>` tag. Not a good idea for production but could help diagnose your problem.

**Option 2**: You can include that javascript from your controller using Requirements::customScript.

**Option 3**: Wrap your js snippet in a non-jquery domready listener like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I will try out a few of these and update this thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally an issue involving the order in which your scripts are called.

As I'm sure you know, you need to call JQuery before Bootstrap, which it seems like you are doing. Your tooltip code, which is in a different file, is most likely being called before your JQuery and Bootstrap have a chance to load. You can test this by copying your JQuery and Bootstrap script calls into your separate file right before the tooltip script call.

If your script calls are at the bottom of your body tag, and part of the page is being dynamically loaded, you can try calling JQuery and Bootstrap in your head tag instead after your CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- 
Your separate file code that
includes tooltip
-->

<!-- Before
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it matter if I am using the CDN href links? Like from Google Hosting or from the Bootstrap CDN, because that is what I am currently using.

Comment: That shouldn't matter if you're including them correctly. You can verify the link is right by trying to navigate to the src in your browser and making sure you see code.

Comment: This doesn't look like SilverStripe code. You'd never have a <?php ?> block in a SilverStripe template.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I'm not familiar with SilverStripe. I just read php system and wasn't sure what method was being used to change views, so I threw that in there just to comment. I'll take it out.